# need help understanding and using wsc files on win64bit

Tags: vbscript, typelib, wsc

I started messing around with making WSC files for my vbscripts but there are a couple of things i
don't quite get to work and understand here...

for example, getObject doesn't seem to work:

**test.WSC:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<component>
<registration
description="MyTest"
progid="My.Test"
version="1.00"
classid="{38b3dd76-c4ee-44d0-978e-4ce2d7e14b0f}"
>
</registration>

<public>
<method name="msg">
<PARAMETER name="this"/>
</method>
</public>

<script language="VBScript">
<![CDATA[

sub msg(this)
msgbox this
end sub

]]>
</script>
</component>
```

**vbscript(in same folder)**

```
set x = getObject("test.wsc")
x.msg "hello world!"
```

if i run this i get this error: VBScript Object required: x , code: 800A01A8

also is it possible to cal methods in a "scriptlet.tlb" from vbscript?
Any help is welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without registration, you have to use the script protocol:

```
set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sFSpec = goFS.GetAbsolutePathName(".\test.wsc")
set x = getObject("script:" & sFSpec)
x.msg "hello world!"
```

study [WSC (Windows Script Components) Without Registration!](http://www.ericphelps.com/scripting/samples/wsc/_readme.txt)

With registration - keep your

```
progid="My.Test"
```

in mind.

Comment: and if the wsc file is in the same dir?

Comment: @Tom It **is** in the same/current folder.

Comment: stumbled on a problem S: , if i executeGlobal the content of a vbscript with a class in it (lets say class test) in a wsc file and try to call it in the main vbscript then i get this error: "object needed: test". should i edit my question and drop the scripts there?